# Proving $g(x)$ is a pdf

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with pdf $f(x)$ and cdf $F(x)$. For fixed values $a$ and $b$ with $ a < b$, define the function 
>   $$g(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> f(x)/(F(b) - F(a)) ,& a\leq x \leq b\\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Prove that $g(x)$ is a pdf. (Assume $F(b) - F(a) > 0$)

Attempted solution - We must show that for $a\leq x \leq b$ $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{F(b)-F(a)}dx = 1$$
We are given that $F(b) - F(a) > 0$, and since $f(x)$ is a pdf we have $f(x)\geq 0$ therefore $g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$.

Thus
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{F(b)-F(a)}dx &= \frac{1}{F(b)-F(a)}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{b}f(x)dx + \int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{F(b)-F(a)}\left[ P(x\leq b) + P(x\geq a)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{F(b)-F(a)}\left[F(b) + 1 - F(a)\right]
\end{align*}

I messed something up here just not sure what, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The bounds are wrong. Where does it does it say that it should be $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$?

Comment: @Max http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206050/how-do-i-tell-if-this-function-is-a-probability-density-function

Comment: You should be aware that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ is more or less a suggestion. Notice that the pdf is defined over $[0,10]$ in that example, so that it becomes $\int_0^{10}$. What about here?

Comment: @Max I see wait so then its quite trivial then we would just have $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = F(b) -F(a)$$ then clearly we have $1$ since $F(b) - F(a)$ would cancel each other  out is it really that easy?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It happens, and notice it's the result we seek!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \,dx
&= \int_{-\infty}^a g(x) \,dx + \int_a^b g(x) \,dx + \int_b^\infty g(x) \,dx \\
&= 0 + \int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{F(b)-F(a)} \,dx + 0 \\
&= \frac{F(b)-F(a)}{F(b)-F(a)} = 1.
\end{align}